# Troubleshooting outbound internet traffic - Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, netstat, tcpdump

Without any programs open except an empty terminal window and System Monitor, I'm seeing network traffic. Roughly every 1 second there's a small spike in outbound and a little inbound traffic. `$ sudo tcpdump -vv -A` shows a pretty much constant polling of random IPs. Snippets of netstat and tcpdump included below. Idling, CPU use is pretty low and nothing stands out in RAM use. How can I find the processes initiating this traffic to either ensure that they're legitimate and/or remove them?

Stackoverflow is limiting input to 30000 characters, so I've truncated or removed output of netstat/tcpdump/ps and will post a linked versions shortly.

**Edit:** Links: [netstat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCJBrjGDimEH5fIQdPOuEcDryz1PYpqE/view?usp=sharing) [tcpdump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NiQoRXYn5W6R3jIL3X5TBMdDOpZ19U_X/view?usp=sharing) [ps](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u5jtFDg4mV23RjgUdfqA8QqH0OzWneCP/view?usp=sharing)

I have postgres and tor running (5432/9050).

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.9.11-100.fc32.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 24 19:16:53 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```bsh
$ netstat -avnp 
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.5:59018      82.165.103.72:443       ESTABLISHED -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5298                 :::*                    LISTEN      11406/telepathy-sal 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
netstat: no support for `AF INET (sctp)' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF INET (sctp)' on this system.
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52467           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36654         127.0.0.1:36654         ESTABLISHED -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.43.5:68         192.168.43.1:67         ESTABLISHED -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::52486                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                -                   
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           -                   
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67663    -                    @/tmp/dbus-pKviT04I
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     53227    -                    @/tmp/.ICE-unix/8573
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67816    9768/gnome-session-  @/tmp/.ICE-unix/9768
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    66631    9477/systemd         /run/user/1000/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    51406    -                    /run/user/42/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     66634    9477/systemd         /run/user/1000/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51409    -                    /run/user/42/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     66641    9477/systemd         /run/user/1000/bus
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51418    -                    /run/user/42/bus
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     66642    9477/systemd         /run/user/1000/pipewire-0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51419    -                    /run/user/42/pipewire-0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     66643    9477/systemd         /run/user/1000/pulse/native
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51420    -                    /run/user/42/pulse/native
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     66644    9477/systemd         /run/user/1000/snapd-session-agent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51421    -                    /run/user/42/snapd-session-agent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     66160    -                    /run/user/1000/keyring/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     52894    -                    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     63365    9508/Xorg            @/tmp/.X11-unix/X1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     46547    -                    /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    1331     -                    /run/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     40772    -                    @irqbalance7670.sock
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    42543    -                    /var/run/chrony/chronyd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67857    -                    /run/user/1000/keyring/pkcs11
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67860    -                    /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
unix  25     [ ]         DGRAM                    1343     -                    /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1345     -                    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  17     [ ]         DGRAM                    1347     -                    /run/systemd/journal/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     52895    -                    /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    42554    -                    /run/systemd/home/notify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     42556    -                    /run/systemd/userdb/io.systemd.Home
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     53228    -                    /tmp/.ICE-unix/8573
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     44662    -                    @/tmp/dbus-BLXNiJvO
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     63366    9508/Xorg            /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     40909    -                    /var/run/mcelog-client
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     63471    -                    /tmp/ssh-jxgRTFKssaxH/agent.9522
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67817    9768/gnome-session-  /tmp/.ICE-unix/9768
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     66417    9766/pulseaudio      /tmp/.esd-1000/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36320    -                    @ISCSID_UIP_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     42933    -                    /var/run/abrt/abrt.socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    511876   -                    @userdb-0bee4a4179405db591eb1f23b10b2ef5
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     46190    -                    /var/lib/gssproxy/default.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     44663    -                    @/tmp/dbus-ahGNYpqL
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     46191    -                    /run/gssproxy.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67092    9812/ibus-daemon     @/home/dave/.cache/ibus/dbus-i8FrV8PD
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     48210    -                    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     57485    -                    @/var/lib/gdm/.cache/ibus/dbus-DKte3KoP
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     31759    -                    /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     31761    -                    /run/systemd/userdb/io.systemd.DynamicUser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     46546    -                    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67662    -                    @/tmp/dbus-IIRpKdPq
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     82818    11081/gpg-agent      /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     82819    11081/gpg-agent      /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     31775    -                    /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     82820    11081/gpg-agent      /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30928    -                    /run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     82821    11081/gpg-agent      /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     30938    -                    /run/systemd/coredump
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     30939    -                    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30941    -                    /run/systemd/userdb/io.systemd.Multiplexer
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     44660    -                    @/tmp/dbus-hAFg9qTn
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     46599    -                    /run/php-fpm/www.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     46783    -                    /run/tor/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36319    -                    @ISCSIADM_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     32933    -                    /run/systemd/journal/io.systemd.journal
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    512559   -                    @userdb-8500a1c0a265cfbe91b58a45b58a3bde
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    511808   -                    @userdb-1b21fdefb8bd190f692ad71a7eef8350
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     53938    -                    @/tmp/dbus-3NH5zvD2zn
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36313    -                    /run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     44661    -                    @/tmp/dbus-j9jAEHL8
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36315    -                    /run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36317    -                    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36321    -                    /run/libvirt/libvirt-sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36323    -                    /run/libvirt/libvirt-admin-sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     57165    -                    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     58014    -                    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     52132    -                    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     54625    -                    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    43076    -                    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     36583    -                    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     95305    11524/seahorse       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     71114    10046/gsd-usb-prote  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     66528    9756/dbus-broker     @00747
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     67097    9520/dbus-broker     /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     42819    -   
netstat: no support for `AF IPX' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF AX25' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF X25' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF NETROM' on this system.
Active Bluetooth connections (servers and established)
Proto  Destination       Source            State         PSM DCID   SCID      IMTU    OMTU Security
netstat: no support for `BTPROTO L2CAP' on this system.
Proto  Destination       Source            State     Channel
netstat: no support for `BTPROTO RFCOMM' on this system.
```

```bsh
$ sudo tcpdump -vv -A
[sudo] password for dave: 
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: listening on wlo1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:52:49.221170 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 5217, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 125)
    den02s01-in-f3.1e100.net.https > localhost.localdomain.33710: Flags [P.], cksum 0xff90 (correct), seq 413833741:413833814, ack 3161770310, win 315, options [nop,nop,TS val 2204560950 ecr 514379669], length 73
E..}.a..7.........+..........t.F...;.......
.f.6........Dgch).y".ox.,...U..h........Djj....r.!.R.oJzI/..$.?LA.Z........d9z...
09:52:49.221543 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12057, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.localdomain.33710 > den02s01-in-f3.1e100.net.https: Flags [F.], cksum 0x08c6 (correct), seq 1, ack 73, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 514619688 ecr 2204560950], length 0
E..4/.@.@.gA..+..........t.F...V...........
..y(.f.6
09:52:49.225340 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 5439, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    localhost.localdomain.42495 > _gateway.domain: [udp sum ok] 21145+ PTR? 5.43.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (43)
E..G.?@.@.N...+...+....5.3.oR............5.43.168.192.in-addr.arpa.....
09:52:49.227321 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 46153, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    _gateway.domain > localhost.localdomain.42495: [udp sum ok] 21145 NXDomain q: PTR? 5.43.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 0/0/0 (43)
E..G.I@.@.....+...+..5...3^.R............5.43.168.192.in-addr.arpa.....
09:52:49.231085 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 5442, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 73)
    localhost.localdomain.40310 > _gateway.domain: [udp sum ok] 53024+ PTR? 227.11.217.172.in-addr.arpa. (45)
E..I.B@.@.N...+...+..v.5.59C. ...........227.11.217.172.in-addr.arpa.....
09:52:49.265963 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 46157, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 111)
    _gateway.domain > localhost.localdomain.40310: [udp sum ok] 53024 q: PTR? 227.11.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 1/0/0 227.11.217.172.in-addr.arpa. PTR den02s01-in-f3.1e100.net. (83)
E..o.M@.@.....+...+..5.v.[... ...........227.11.217.172.in-addr.arpa.............5....den02s01-in-f3.1e100.net.
09:52:49.271587 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 5463, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    localhost.localdomain.33612 > _gateway.domain: [udp sum ok] 63879+ PTR? 1.43.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (43)
E..G.W@.@.M...+...+..L.5.3[8.............1.43.168.192.in-addr.arpa.....
09:52:49.273258 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 46158, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    _gateway.domain > localhost.localdomain.33612: [udp sum ok] 63879 NXDomain q: PTR? 1.43.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 0/0/0 (43)
E..G.N@.@.....+...+..5.L.3...............1.43.168.192.in-addr.arpa.....
09:52:49.289081 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 5242, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    den02s01-in-f3.1e100.net.https > localhost.localdomain.33710: Flags [F.], cksum 0x0928 (correct), seq 73, ack 2, win 315, options [nop,nop,TS val 2204561037 ecr 514619688], length 0
E..4.z..7.........+........V.t.G...;    (.....
.f....y(
09:52:49.289168 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12058, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.localdomain.33710 > den02s01-in-f3.1e100.net.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x082a (correct), seq 2, ack 74, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 514619756 ecr 2204561037], length 0
E..4/.@.@.g@..+..........t.G...W.....*.....
..yl.f..
09:52:52.994807 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 44, id 52683, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 588)
    82.165.103.72.https > localhost.localdomain.59018: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa3b8 (correct), seq 347695786:347696322, ack 4205776962, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4039827458 ecr 1207355784], length 536
E..L..@.,..ER.gH..+.......j....B...........
....G........{-.5v.&.....g....t&.k....@.&p:.{...A.;....._Z..
....A...s.|.........z.S.n.1.,..c.. ....]...f...BA.@m&....a:\1...Xz.+.,.........P^ }X.T..K . ..L....V. n....X... .0....s...... :.RH.M.(...2..$.?9....>G.)5)06..$...._:<.Nz2Zq..^.&.w.........f..../....*G..FF$N*.RfL..(?.F...H..... ..*Y.....,.i.@..%.f>......@..(O....m.}i.}...<...8.'..:C.N..h@..s..+.e.;  f.....GAZ.n....n-.x^".afsR...%..e...3.9.a.......R...r...
!.. .z..\s..".............}%..?.:.`..GA7..T.kM...2......xx......'..-mJ...e.....p.......VRO;+.......5.w{..L.b%..Jv........`....T
09:52:52.994941 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38645, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.localdomain.59018 > 82.165.103.72.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x5f9e (correct), seq 1, ack 536, win 762, options [nop,nop,TS val 1207361810 ecr 4039827458], length 0
E..4..@.@..3..+.R.gH.......B..l....._......
G.......
09:52:53.001866 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6726, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    localhost.localdomain.34678 > _gateway.domain: [udp sum ok] 43806+ PTR? 72.103.165.82.in-addr.arpa. (44)
E..H.F@.@.I...+...+..v.5.4.?.............72.103.165.82.in-addr.arpa.....
09:52:53.006443 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 46924, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    _gateway.domain > localhost.localdomain.34678: [udp sum ok] 43806 NXDomain q: PTR? 72.103.165.82.in-addr.arpa. 0/0/0 (44)
E..H.L@.@.....+...+..5.v.4)..............72.103.165.82.in-addr.arpa.....
09:52:59.715841 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 44, id 52684, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 588)
    82.165.103.72.https > localhost.localdomain.59018: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0289 (correct), seq 536:1072, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4039834165 ecr 1207361810], length 536
E..L..@.,..DR.gH..+.......l....B...........
...5G.........  .-Zw=.6#802...V
`G..a.WRT.<..........,.wtl\...48Zl....6.i..e.g.dL...S...|L>oN.\..4..z.z.7"a...'zA.Z....7+?Q....Y.?'Bcu.#.%.D....:.,..."....3...W.D2.Y8..8..+.........Ue..>l..........3.0.4.tcLe..Q....Oy..e....B./U5..jh.....Gdv..K....n...i.z............V[F.J.C..Z~F..J
e.e^>
.w*.0g........C+.y?...._.....5(.....I..7-............'4.X.s..;.<p.2r.q.....C.r..C{.q...LA.....9g...HI...3..A......
cN1..:.%@...Kt{......
8c..%..N."...6..G....lX...v...f.0..9...S`n/G....J...>.G..o...{u...I........+...e.p.....-................G....v...Tn...T.
09:52:59.715967 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38646, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.localdomain.59018 > 82.165.103.72.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x2912 (correct), seq 1, ack 1072, win 762, options [nop,nop,TS val 1207368531 ecr 4039834165], length 0
E..4..@.@..2..+.R.gH.......B..n.....)......
G..S...5
09:53:01.331562 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 42377, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.localdomain.58794 > den02s02-in-f14.1e100.net.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x9c11 (correct), seq 941105926, ack 2407933939, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3918337418 ecr 796134296], length 0
E..4..@.@.....+.........8.#...'............
..../t..
09:53:01.338695 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6950, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    localhost.localdomain.47838 > _gateway.domain: [udp sum ok] 11291+ PTR? 14.12.217.172.in-addr.arpa. (44)
E..H.&@.@.H(..+...+....5.4V.,............14.12.217.172.in-addr.arpa.....
09:53:01.395143 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 48250, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 111)
    _gateway.domain > localhost.localdomain.47838: [udp sum ok] 11291 q: PTR? 14.12.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 1/0/0 14.12.217.172.in-addr.arpa. PTR den02s02-in-f14.1e100.net. (83)
E..o.z@.@.....+...+..5...[..,............14.12.217.172.in-addr.arpa..................den02s02-in-f14.1e100.net.
09:53:01.399966 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 118, id 63042, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    den02s02-in-f14.1e100.net.https > localhost.localdomain.58794: Flags [.], cksum 0x9cf8 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 269, options [nop,nop,TS val 796181908 ecr 3918289806], length 0
E..4.B..v.........+.......'.8.#............
/t....[.
09:53:02.151026 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 44, id 52685, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 588)
    82.165.103.72.https > localhost.localdomain.59018: Flags [P.], cksum 0x249d (correct), seq 1072:1608, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4039836587 ecr 1207368531], length 536
E..L..@.,..CR.gH..+.......n....B....$......
....G..S.......}{.'..F ....w.#;X....a..7.2..&......S.i./.#. .df...Y..M.+.....O......Q.. .6{....Q1J...7,..C.s..kY.=....?.h(....(..2Q...r.S...4.G3.}....^s....k.x&.....wk..MHms.g.h.......V..........Vx...b..^C.....E..mD..V.7f8YE..q#.T.V..,T....t/.......Y......    .tf`.Ld..?6'...S<0.q_u..#.tO38....  ....g.~..&r$5sXo.a.....:H...L.7 ....>h.q=..u.n|.S.......h...A}%.1...+l.......-...VWU*.<.....a.[ .O.fJ.M ...
..7.3paz.+......-.r...}..G. |.7....1^.z..F......    .@..Z....i.dXh..e.#.H.-d...E)....1..........E.N[.q.D1..3..}..]..e.l.l.>)j.4.q.....x...D..h}....
09:53:02.151147 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38647, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.localdomain.59018 > 82.165.103.72.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x1401 (correct), seq 1, ack 1608, win 762, options [nop,nop,TS val 1207370966 ecr 4039836587], length 0
E..4..@.@..1..+.R.gH.......B..p............
G.......
09:53:04.643208 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38648, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1394)
    localhost.localdomain.59018 > 82.165.103.72.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x33b0 (correct), seq 1:1343, ack 1608, win 762, options [nop,nop,TS val 1207373458 ecr 4039836587], length 1342
E..r..@.@.....+.R.gH.......B..p.....3......
G.............r. ..'...N?1...q...EK>g.. .....v...u...=5....rDZpq...m....|....3...1o.Zs.k....6.....kQ....bw...J.~i..Q.......a.C.T^.en..eF<.>.d.Of1.5.l........^.,..<r.....i.......B3......W:..\...I.....}..j.......q.fctG...R.9..c.  Fx..9..q..&..._..z.KP.R..)..-7M.c...b........(].........!_...IG....=B.{jmH....XUB
5.qfV..p ..Z.......@.............'e.... .^..!"..[L...&r-.....).q..|r.yO.w.xxhh...............~.b..o.. ......h:@.P.....J..j...   `...............w...m.'..._t.w..K..#...^m .G.m..e...89..!........... ...".
a._..#...2..Y.....\..S3&.<.mkz..8...Fn=[H.$.R.HI..YB.@H.=K.U...t....a b.vK...9.g.V....q.Q<.3.2.8......g.V....O..y1.:.VR..O....ks~Qq....
.:.y.   ..$.U...F.....O..3o-./.~._y.P..D...;...Z......G..#!-...!...............P.#<....%...+../......A(.BU .....c.!..........~#.&zc...z..K.a.^........nO,...On;yT)...q...>G..v|c}.d.f...a.N.5..E......_.|..k.l......:........z-r.......Nap....>.9?.5#C..5f.t.....l..."J_.n.....lY..v..$hej.*}...cj......$.5........S/.!.D."uW..t.M..!et......{_?0+U...s..K.q).Igr.....\..,......V....A.....7.....bE.w[11."..:..i.Gz...xZv..U%...-<~.Y6eJ.:p.,....W..,......sk>1J.!"9..]..Z$....Z.._....{@.F..-..L8.z...u..v..3Q..)>s.......\...1.....]...'f.w.3...vK...... ..c0...}..S.p.|..<g%&...4!.[h)..T....F....J%.... ...c...B.....`....."..,..\tHyz|..8SD..}........+h...=Z..J..E..%t.K>....K.(..26..........    ....M.T..c2f}.P.t+. ..R...S.i
09:53:04.643260 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38649, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 788)
    localhost.localdomain.59018 > 82.165.103.72.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfa89 (correct), seq 1343:2079, ack 1608, win 762, options [nop,nop,TS val 1207373458 ecr 4039836587], length 736
E.....@.@..O..+.R.gH..........p............
G..........dg.qf...5k..[....uw.s.......E..s...?'..*.D..'K.~......FEO@..-u..ng.}...g.l.'.B}.Tf.k.D) ..!+I.......p...|...+R*>.....c%M>.;...........l. O..0..w`.$=.u.7.s.....Xr....-.U.:..;...^...F.U"YN]....&...:B\W.W.....a...^..v+.......k_......o.....fp...tKw.[&.-O....'.0./...DMk...#.9A_8. (....    ..o.[-..m.........p.X.....LQ4M.0....B~..........%....%.9.uXi..1...p.7PC.c..~.k.xzr.....t0.D..e@QhU....  ...K.,1...dO......W.hW.C.s....(.^.b6.........E.6]..^...c..QY.%.cs...,. .kj.......'.".th\b..O.B.........'.jv..5..'4 .^...v6...d.u.......C.........|..^w.../))..|....<i....H1..e.(.....
.>.L....9....D].~.n<...G].20.R,Q..=&..y...W+.......x.&.b....5.........o+...Y.   .Y........AW M*.e.4`..T........G..:f.s..T...C....3$.!....l..eU....K..P...)..a..`.T.&~W.
09:53:04.731655 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has localhost.localdomain tell _gateway, length 28
...........KL...+.........+.
09:53:04.731705 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply localhost.localdomain is-at 10:0b:a9:4e:f4:48 (oui Unknown), length 28
...........N.H..+....KL...+.
09:53:04.847887 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 44, id 52686, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.165.103.72.https > localhost.localdomain.59018: Flags [.], cksum 0xfb5f (correct), seq 1608, ack 1343, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4039839319 ecr 1207373458], length 0
E..4..@.,..ZR.gH..+.......p.........._.....
...WG...
09:53:04.848003 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 44, id 52687, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.165.103.72.https > localhost.localdomain.59018: Flags [.], cksum 0xf884 (correct), seq 1608, ack 2079, win 496, options [nop,nop,TS val 4039839319 ecr 1207373458], length 0
E..4..@.,..YR.gH..+.......p....`...........
...WG...
09:53:04.857146 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 44, id 52688, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 588)
    82.165.103.72.https > localhost.localdomain.59018: Flags [P.], cksum 0xaf5b (correct), seq 1608:2144, ack 2079, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4039839328 ecr 1207373458], length 536
E..L..@.,..@R.gH..+.......p....`.....[.....
...`G.........F..5H......%.......=.^0.  ..U...P.EQ..,Ru.<..48.k...HI.X~...
0.0F6;]...I4-..qP../..|."...@.}o.k.../.!C.c.....!.......z..e"AJ..?`...: ..x.n..8o.<*J.f<..NW.....f.~....XS..
.Iwf..~...Y..D2.Y.b.`......:q....ZG...=......2....$......S..F...6..A..Q_s..Z).*..._.b&.`.....R;.r...!_-`...Nf/...7..%+.'.....p......K.].PB......H................m......Ij.F|...K...*A.......|.UyP...~;..}..}WB%{+..g
. V"..........%..-......Z..\H.....'=..P...9..[...|v..y...V.....R...I...L...Y.....I......K.....:..o..>7....Z......j..;....b.W...6.c9g....J1e..l.h3-.
09:53:04.857263 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38650, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    localhost.localdomain.59018 > 82.165.103.72.https: Flags [.], cksum 0xf483 (correct), seq 2079, ack 2144, win 762, options [nop,nop,TS val 1207373672 ecr 4039839328], length 0
E..4..@.@.....+.R.gH.......`..s
...........
G..h...`
09:53:04.858672 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38651, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 588)
    localhost.localdomain.59018 > 82.165.103.72.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd966 (correct), seq 2079:2615, ack 2144, win 762, options [nop,nop,TS val 1207373674 ecr 4039839328], length 536
E..L..@.@.....+.R.gH.......`..s
.....f.....
G..j...`.......w...Pa.. -...8....i..+8.na..5.d..)...qMU.........L..~.k...5......L4...../.;....,......<.Q.].(Nl.O.N..zD...}..6....U../\.g.....Y....!n.u..`..A...zc.....[..E.......x....(.'..W.$..............r..........C...~    <....LL..G.`..;.z|.......qBAm%Nf..Gt..m.....2..u...L....lG..A..lC..b.X&.....(..#.Q....T.{`.:..{.e
...!$.'.(<&v......d..Qb.."b.#......~MD..O..#....H.T...:T..>..r>....Q..xI....|6mG.77..DrQ..OtQ..2..[...Pf'.......{a..:dq_;;..Q..O.o.q.0.|u.U..N1....O..+..G....C...L..;a...Y...^(+..o.U.=...`.......;.?.......O....8..3..|;.o.:..A
09:53:05.027720 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 44, id 52689, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 588)
    82.165.103.72.https > localhost.localdomain.59018: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5d6e (correct), seq 2144:2680, ack 2615, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4039839499 ecr 1207373674], length 536
E..L..@.,..?R.gH..+.......s
...x....]n.....
....G..j..........0.........B..g.j.Ha=f..................'.&....;lk..Z...^q......X.\.....v........zu{..+gI.X.K5;T..Vfs|...l..d..............Y.f7.v......gr.q....`.`...O....K.XG].t.Q..B...cXxw.....Xo:H..r$....L u.$<...iL.B)CY.:....L...i(9.b.. /.%....O...805....nW'....n...t8D..x.b..........w...'.yh..J#5..7.=.l..Yx~.)....`I3.2O<....#.x.....).nf.[.b. #.m....h..3...
.(vV..~?SI8..x.9b.*.!..Yp.y...4#...>......N.A.....r_... 9N.th.x....;F*.............w/...v.....|.p......uX....!...i..Y..S.3x.r."VU{......1)L.h...8...L$.F.o].Y5a*...FPF.q .Lr.....
...
09:53:05.029099 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38652, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 588)
    localhost.localdomain.59018 > 82.165.103.72.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0xff8b (correct), seq 2615:3151, ack 2680, win 762, options [nop,nop,TS val 1207373844 ecr 4039839499], length 536
E..L..@.@.....+.R.gH.......x..u"...........
G............6......@.!.L[2s.....P.G.c..P...uk....G.f=x.<..K.....u...\....<AU......o...oV...../....J..gw.2TNG.......H_....V.x.e."...w.._.Yg.a..K1..H'.0.u`..1.i...7...\Nh.|...g.i=X%..e.:.e$...=.:mH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Run netstat as user root

The `netstat` output shows one TCP session that is generating traffic seen in `tcpdump`:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.5:59018      82.165.103.72:443       ESTABLISHED -
```

You should run the netstat command as user `root` to display the `PID` and `process name` of the process that establishes this TCP session.

#### Trace network activity of the process

Once you have the PID, you may want to investigate more thoroughly the network traffic generated by the process using:

```
strace -f -e trace=network -p <PID>
```

#### Disable tcpdump addresses conversion

Also, in order to better compare the `tcpdump` output with the `netstat` one, you may want to execute `tcpdump` with the `-n` option to disable conversion of addresses to names:

```
       -n     Don't convert addresses (i.e., host addresses, port numbers, etc.) to names.
```